# Random code generator for coupon system

Tags: php, random

Is this good enough for a random coupon code generator? Should I check and see if a code has already been used when I make a new code? What are the odds that this will repeat?

```
$coupon_code = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 7);
```

EDIT - here's my actual code:

```
$coupon_code = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 7);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM generatedcoupons WHERE coupon_code='$coupon_code' LIMIT 1"));
if($numrows>0){
     $coupon_code =  substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(rand())), 16, 36), 0, 7);
     $numrows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM generatedcoupons WHERE coupon_code='$coupon_code' LIMIT 1"));
     if($numrows>0)
          //error, show link to retry
}
```

Comment: If each item that will have a unique coupon has an ID, then hash the ID. If each purchase transaction that will generate a unique coupon has an ID, then hash that ID. (*or, don't hash anything and just use the ID, such that you're using an RDBMS with an `INT` or other likely candidate type for a primary key*)

Comment: *Should I check and see if a code has already been used when I make a new code.* If you need each code to be actually uniquely referenced in your system, with no duplicates, and they aren't something like an incrementer: **Yes**.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - they're going to be printed and used with many different "business owners". Sorry if this is a rookie question I have no formal educaiton...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a coupon system that not only guarantees unique codes, but is very efficient when it comes to looking them up:

```
// assuming MySQL table with (id, code, effect)
mysql_query( "insert into `coupons` set `effect`='".$effect."'");
// "effect" will be some keyword to identify what the coupon does
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$code = $id."F";
$codelen = 32; // change as needed
for( $i=strlen($code); $i<$codelen; $i++) {
    $code .= dechex(rand(0,15));
}
mysql_query( "update `coupons` set `code`='".$code."' where `id`=".$id);

// now, when you are given a code to redeem, say $_POST['code']
list($code,$effect) = mysql_fetch_row( mysql_query( "select `code`, `effect` from `coupons` where `id`='".((int) $_POST['code'])."'"));
if( $code != $_POST['code']) die("Code not valid");
else {
    // do something based on $effect
}
```

As you can see, it takes the ID from `AUTO_INCREMENT`, appends an F, then pads with random hexadecimal characters. You can make `$codelen` as high as you want, but 32 should be plenty (giving around 16**26 combinations even after the millionth coupon).

Comment: To make it unique, shouldn't it be `$code = $id."G";` instead of `$code = $id."F";`? If it is `"F"`, there's a small probability that it generates an already existent code because `F` could be also generated on the for loop right?

Comment: No, because the format of the code is: [ID of the coupon in decimal] [literal F] [random hex digits]. Since the ID can never have an F in it, then that F will always be the first non-numeric character. Since the ID part is unique, then all codes are unique.

Comment: Ah... Forget, my mistake. What I was thinking would generate, for example "12FFA1C3" and not "12FA1C3" for `ID=12` and `code=FA1C3`.

Comment: Could be. It could even be random, so long as it's a letter and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fairly random to me... I'd still probably double check that a code has not already been used when you create one on the very slight off chance that you do get a repetitive number.

And most likely the chances of a repetition are slightly more than 1 in 36^8 or roughly 1:2,821,109,907,456.

Note that since SHA1 gives back 40 digits in a hexadecimal string if you want there to be less chance that it will be duplicated you can always just increase your substr from (0,7) up to (0,29) (you can go even a little higher, but I doubt you want THAT big of a number)

But I defs agree you should have some sort of unique coupon id stored in some database for making sure that you don't have duplicates, and it would be a great way to see how many coupons you guys created (and potentially how many got used? =D)